# How to cite a translation of works published across multiple years?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I am using `biblatex-apa` and `biber` as backend.

According to Biblatex package [documentaiton](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for the field origdate`

> Date ranges are given as yyyy-mm-dd/yyyy-mm-dd (p. 34)

Still I am not sure how to print it because if I have a translation then with the data range the in-text citation would be `Someauthor (1929-1939/1965)`; a bit messy. 
The `biblatex-apa` style doesn't support date range for original date: it prints only the first year. But in any case how would you print it? Would you keep both the first and last year of the range or just the last one?

Comment: Doesn't the APA style guide itself give a ruling on this?  The Chicago Manual of Style recommends as a possibility using in-text whichever date is considered of greater importance, and mentioning the other date only in the reference list.  However, some styles insist on using both dates, which would mean the very clunky '(1929-1939/1965)'.  Of course, I find the in-text citation style adds little to the elegance of anyone's prose, so maybe it's not really a big deal to use both dates....

Comment: Yes, according to the APA the data range should be indicated `somebody (1914-1918)`, still I couldn't find what to do with both range and original date of publication.

Comment: Yeah, I hope someone can point to a definitive reference for this kind of situation.  I've never needed the APA style and do not possess any books on the subject (and if APA is as stingy as Chicago is with what is freely available online, it may be hard to find!).

Comment: APA is indeed stingy. You have to buy the official manual. Your case really needs handling by using the "related entries" feature of biblatex+biber. That way you don't really need the "ORIGDATE" field which is a compromise anyway. See section 3.4 of the biblatex manual. The `biblatex-apa-references.bib` which comes with the APA style also has examples - search for "RELATED" (uppercase) to see related entries in action.

Answer (score 2):

We can redefine the macros using `origyear` to also print the `origendyear`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{origyear}{\mkbibparens{\bibcpstring{origyear}~\thefield{origyear}\setunit*{\bibrangedash}\printfield{origendyear}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield[noformat]{origyear}\setunit*{\bibrangedash}\printfield[noformat]{origendyear}
       \setunit{\addslash}%
       \printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}}}
```

Thus we also get to set the end date of the range.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{popper-logik:eng:1959,
  author      = {Karl R. Popper},
  title       = {The Logic of Scientific Discovery},
  date        = {1959},
  edition     = {1},
  location    = {London},
  publisher   = {Hutchinson},
  origdate    = {1934/1935},
}

@book{Poincare:1928-GER,
  author          = {Jules-Henri Poincaré},
  title           = {Wissenschaft und Hypothese},
  date            = {1928},
  publisher       = {Teubner},
  location        = {Berlin and Leipzig},
  origdate        = {1902/1905},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{origyear}{\mkbibparens{\bibcpstring{origyear}~\thefield{origyear}\setunit*{\bibrangedash}\printfield{origendyear}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield[noformat]{origyear}\setunit*{\bibrangedash}\printfield[noformat]{origendyear}
       \setunit{\addslash}%
       \printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}}}

\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
  Here is some sample text \parencite{popper-logik:eng:1959,Poincare:1928-GER}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

`biblatex` has more sophisticated mechanisms available to deal with this kind of connection though (the `related` field), plus it seems unnecessary to me to print the original year of publication in an in-text citation.